# LEAD and LAG in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am trying to identify if a template has been applied after saving a ticket.
The code does run, but it does not capture the strings "template applied" from the *ACTION* column.

This is table where I'm getting the data:

[image]

Here is the results I am getting:

[image]

My code:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT              
         [ACTION], 
         CASE
            WHEN ACTION = 'Save' AND LAG(ACTION) OVER (ORDER BY SYS_CREATED_BY, SYS_CREATED_ON) LIKE 'Template Applied%' AND LAG(SYS_CREATED_BY) OVER (ORDER BY SYS_CREATED_BY, SYS_CREATED_ON) = SYS_CREATED_BY 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
         END AS RELEVANT_SAVE, 
         [TICKET_NUMBER], 
         [USER_ID], 
         [SYS_CREATED_BY], [SYS_CREATED_ON], 
         DATEPART(YEAR, [SYS_CREATED_ON]) AS YEAR, 
         DATEPART(MONTH, [SYS_CREATED_ON]) AS month
     FROM            
         TICKETSDB
     WHERE        
         (ACTION = 'Save' OR ACTION LIKE 'Template Applied%')) AS T
```

Comment: So what’s the expected results? Your results show two columns but you are returning 8. What gives?

Comment: Oh, didn't show all the other columns on the screenshot. My desired results to have "1" under RELEVANT_SAVE column when it's "template applied" in the ACTION column.

Comment: Are you sure you want created by in the order by? It does t seem right. If you are trying to group this by person, add the created by the a partition statement. Can you elaborate on this

Comment: What I am trying to capture is that, if " that person" used a template in a ticket then eventually in my excel report count how many times did that person used a template for all his tickets. So in SQL i am not trying to group it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to move part of the `order by` to `partition by`

In both `lead` and `lag` statements change the `over` clause to

```
OVER (PARTITION BY SYS_CREATED_BY ORDER BY SYS_CREATED_ON DESC)
```

This will fix where you want to view it by person.

Or remove it completely if you don’t care

```
 OVER ( ORDER BY SYS_CREATED_ON)
```

Comment: The code did run, but there's a row under ACTION cokumn that has "Template applied" and it returned "0" instead of "1".

Comment: Change the order to DESC and see if that fixes it. I edited my answer @Jonathan